# R How to use pairwise.t.test values

Tags: r

Im using the pairwise.t.test command and I have the following variables:

```
bestID = 28

> ptt <- pairwise.t.test(aovFrame$partAvg,aovFrame$id,p.adjust="bonf", conf.level = 0.95)
> ptt

    Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  aovFrame$partAvg and aovFrame$id 

   12     13     15     24     28     29    
13 <2e-16 -      -      -      -      -     
15 <2e-16 <2e-16 -      -      -      -     
24 <2e-16 <2e-16 <2e-16 -      -      -     
28 <2e-16 <2e-16 <2e-16 <2e-16 -      -     
29 <2e-16 2e-16  <2e-16 <2e-16 <2e-16 -     
30 <2e-16 <2e-16 1      <2e-16 <2e-16 <2e-16

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

with the `bestID` indicates me (as index) which id I want to compare to all other ids, and extract its p-value. if the p-value between both ids is < 0.05 then I want to add that id (not the 28) to a list.

You can see in the code that all the pairs of 28 (by column and by row) are not similar to 28.

The problem is that I dont know how to access the paired.t.test fields by INDEX

using `str(ptt)` will output the following:

```
List of 4
 $ method         : chr "t tests with pooled SD"
 $ data.name      : chr "aovFrame$partAvg and aovFrame$id"
 $ p.value        : num [1:6, 1:6] 2.12e-20 1.11e-154 0.00 7.24e-26 1.19e-66 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "13" "15" "24" "28" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "12" "13" "15" "24" ...
 $ p.adjust.method: chr "bonferroni"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "pairwise.htest"
```

I cant understand from this how to access the INDEX

Comment: Please clarify the question. Your criterion `bestID > 0.05` does not make sense, as `bestID` seems to be an integer index (as far as I can tell).  Are you asking how to extract the p-values from `ptt`?

Comment: As you said. bestID is just the index. the 28 that is both in the column and in the row. Im asking how to extract the p-value. So i can compare, for example between id 28 and 29 (and the p-value there is <2e-16)

Comment: See what you can learn by examining the structure of `ptt` using `str(ptt)`.  If this doesn't solve your problem, let us know.

Comment: Im sorry but I cant understand from this structure how to access the Indexes.

Comment: What to you mean by "access the Indexes"?  I thought you wanted to access the p-values.

Comment: I cannot access the p-value BY index..

Comment: You can see from `str(ptt)` that the p values are all sitting in `ptt$p.value`

Comment: I know that.. And how do I access the 28 id and compare it to all the other id's? its impossible. The only thing I've managed to do is ptt$p.value[4,] but on the fly its not a solution because i dont know where my desired INDEX will be

Comment: `ptt$p.value` has row names.

Comment: It looks like to access them i needed to do ptt$p.value[as.character(28),] I think it might work!

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution!  Just to bring this full circle, I think your question might best be phrased as "I need an automated way to extract the p-values from `ppt` corresponding to `bestID`. Our solution using the rownames is a good one.  Alternatively, you could use your initial dataframe to figure out the row number where `28` is going to live (turns out it's the 4th row) and call it based on its numeric index (as you suggested above).

Comment: Oh but I cant.. I dont know which groups Id's will be created on the fly.. it could be 2 groups.. 10 groups.. or 100 groups. So no way to predict them by place, Only by name! and its good. Just run with a for loop over the p-values/names(...) already done it ;] Thank mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question "I need an automated way to extract the p-values from `ptt` corresponding to `bestID`" (see comment thread on OP):

```
ptt$p.value[as.character(bestID),]
```